# practice and discovery of Boost Type Erasure

Tags: c++, boost, type-erasure

I am reading about `boost type erasure` and I am trying to figure out the potential usage. I would like to practice it a bit while I am reading tons of documentations about the topic (it looks a big one). The most quoted area of application that is networking / exchanging data between client and server.
Can you suggest some other example or exercise where I can play I bit with this library?

Comment: page 16ff of http://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload116.pdf has an article about dyamic C++ using type erasure

Comment: I am reading it right now. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I'd say for networking, classic runtime polymorphism is a more appropriate idiom than type erasure. Type erasure is great for handling deleters and allocators in `std::shared_ptr`, though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Type Erasure is useful in an extraordinary amount of situations, to the point where it may actually be thought of as a fundamentally missing language feature that bridges generic and object oriented programming styles.

When we define a class in C++, what we are really defining is both a very specific `type` and a very specific `interface`, and that these two things do not necessarily need to be related. A `type` deals with the data, where as the `interface` deals with transformations on that data. Generic code, such as in the STL, doesn't care about `type`, it cares about `interface`: you can sort anything container or container-like sequence using `std::sort`, as long as it provides comparison and iterator `interface`.

Unfortunately, generic code in C++ requires compile time polymorphism: `templates`. This doesn't help with things which cannot be known until runtime, or things which require a uniform interface.

A simple example is this: how do you store a number of different types in a single container? The simplest mechanism would be to store all of the types in a void*, perhaps with some type information to distinguish them. Another way is to recognize all of these `types` have the same `interface`: retrieval. If we could make a single interface for `retrieval`, then specialize it for each type, then it would be as if part of the `type` had been erased.

`any_iterator` is another very useful reason to do this: if you need to iterate over a number of different containers with the same interface, you will need to erase the `type` of the container out of the `type` of the iterator. boost::any_range is a subtle enhancement of this, extending it from iterators to ranges, but the basic idea is the same.

In short, any time you need to go from multiple `types` with a similar `interface` to a single `type` with a single `interface`, you will need some form of type erasure. It is the runtime technique that equates compile time templates.

Comment: Hi. In the meantime, for reference I've also read the following  from Thomas Becker
http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html
http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/any_iterator.html

Comment: Both excellent resources, but I thought you might wish to know of the much more general need for type erasure, beyond `any` or `any_iterator` or `any_container`. Much as member function pointers only exist to implement delegates, it may be the case virtual functions exist primarily to allow type erasure. It's that fundamental of a concept.